# How to obtain catalog price rule expire date?

Tags: magento-1.7, catalog, price

On catalog page I need to show offer "expires in **N** days". 
It can be easily achieved if each product has defined *Special Price* and date individually for example `$this->getProduct()->getSpecialToDate();`, but if you set discount via *Catalog Price Rule* product has no information about discount currently applied and other related data.

I'm wandering how can I get information about current product discount rules used like date?

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried this, but I believe it's possible. I don't have the exact code, but I can provide you with it later when I have more free time if you really need it. This appraoch is pretty straightforward.

There's a table called `catalogrule_product` that stores `Catalog Price Rules` discounts per product and customer group. Note that this table needs to get indexed every time you make changes to your `Catalog Price Rules`. You can do this with the indexer or by clicking "Apply Rules" on this page (this could take long if you have a lot of products).

For a given product you have on a catalog (or any) page, get its `entity_id` and look it up on `catalogrule_product.product_id`. Make sure to check `customer_group_id` as well. Once you find the row(s) you're looking for, this row(s) will have have timestamps (in seconds) `from_time` and `to_time` for that given applied rule (`rule_id`).

Get its `row_id` and look this up on `catalogrule` if you need more information on the rule. The entry you find on `catalogrule` has `from_date` and `to_date`, and those are all you need to calculate what you want.

Comment: I think this approach is good, but be careful, I'm thinking about what happens if you have two rules on the same product? There is a column sort_order, however it is calculated, maybe it is useful?

Comment: It's possible that more than one rule applies for a given product, but Magento may index only the rule that applies for a given product. I haven't tested this. OP could probably run a few test scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which worked for me in this case.....

Created one function to sort the things.

```
function getCatalogSalePrice($_product)
{
 $productId = $_product->getId();
 $storeId = $_product->getStoreId();
 $websiteId = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getWebsiteId();
 $timeStamp = Mage::app()->getLocale()->storeTimeStamp($storeId);
 $customerGroupId = 1;

 $resource = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogrule/rule');
 $rules = $resource->getRulesFromProduct($timeStamp, $websiteId, $customerGroupId, $productId);
 foreach($rules as $ruleval)
 {
  $catalogRuleID = $ruleval['rule_id']; //If more than one rule
  if($catalogRuleID)
  {
   $catalogRulObj = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->load($catalogRuleID);
   $conditions_serialized = unserialize($catalogRulObj->getConditionsSerialized());
   $actions_serialized = unserialize($catalogRulObj->getActionsSerialized());
   $ruleToDate = $catalogRulObj->getToDate();
  }
 }
 $now = time(); // or your date as well
 $saleEndDate = strtotime($ruleToDate);
 $datediff = $now - $saleEndDate;
 $datediff = floor($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));

 if($datediff <= 0)
 {
  if($datediff < 0) {
   $message = abs($datediff). " Days Left";
  }
  else
  {
  $message = "Few Hours Left";
  }
 } 
 return $message;   
}
```

Cheers if it works.